# How to change the value of Boolean Field in Model from the views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

The application I've been working uses

- Class Based Views

has

- two models, Question and Answer.

The Question model has a `FileField` to store the actual solution to that question and the Answer model has a `FileField` named `result` to store the solution given by the user ( as solved by the user ).

- a Boolean Field named `iscorrect` in the Answer model which is set to False by default.

I want to

- check if the two files are identical ( the solution in the Question model and the result in the Answer model ) and,
- toggle the BooleanField `iscorrect` ( as mentioned above, this Boolean Field is present in the Answer model ).

What does my question boil down to?

Assuming that I have figured out how to check whether two files are identical ( using a `comparator` method in the `views.py` and then requesting Question model's file for the particular id, then checking if they are identical. To be fair, I haven't implemented that yet so help with that would be appreciated as well ), I want to know how to toggle the BooleanField from the `views.py` based on what my comparator method returns ( True or False ).

Note : As I've stated earlier, I'm using Class Based Views so answer keeping that in mind, thanks.

```
class CoderListView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "coder/coder_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'question'


class CoderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "coder/coder_detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'question'


class CoderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['result']
    context_object_name = 'answer'
    template_name = "coder/coder_form.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        question = self.object.question
        return reverse('coder:detail', kwargs={'pk': question.id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.question = Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['qid'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The view in which I want the changes ( toggling of a boolean field based on the returned value of a comparator method is the CodeCreateView since the user would submit the file and then my method would check if it's identical to the solution or not ).

Comment: Not totally sure what the question is about. Are you asking how to set an answer's `is_correct` field? Something like `answer.is_correct = ...` and then `answer.save()` would do, no?

Comment: yeah, im asking how to setup that field and how to toggle it in the views based on certain conditions.

Comment: Please share a bit more as to how your view looks like. Otherwise the answer seems trivial and is just in the above comment, but it feels that there might be more to it, but not sure without seeing the part of the code you are trying to address.

Comment: alright, im adding my view to the question. p.s i haven't prepared my comparator method as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could do something like this in your `CoderCreateView`:

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['qid'])
        form.instance.question = question
        form.instance.question.is_correct = comparator(question.solution, form.instance.result)
        form.instance.question.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

There are a few things that don't make sense in the code you quoted:

CreateView would require you to specify the `form_class` or override `.get_form_class()` to get a form that deals with he incoming data. You are using this form in `form_valid` so I'm assuming that's taken care of but was just not included in your question.

Assuming that's taken care and the form is a ModelForm the above should work.

Comment: but since I'm using the CreateView, I don't think I need to use any form class, right? The CreateView takes care of it if you pass in the `fields`.
Also, how would `form.instance.is_correct` change the boolean state of my model's boolean field? I'm not saying it necessraliy does not but what's the logic behind it?
Cause in my opinion, doing that shouldn't make a difference to the model's field but if it does, it's great. I'll let you know once I try that out and will accept this answer.

Comment: > "how would form.instance.is_correct change the boolean state of my model's boolean field"
This happens when you call the super().form_valid(). That will take the form.instance and persist it in storage (database) through the model - that's part of the logic that the CreateView provides.